# CMake get dependent header files like gcc -M

Tags: gcc, makefile, cmake

I'm analyzing a CMake project and I want to get all the header files that a source file depends on. Is there a tool or a command like `gcc -M` or `g++ -M` to list all the dependencies of one file in the CMake project? It would be better if I could also get which Target each header file belongs to.

Of course I can’t use `g++ -M` directly because it can’t find some dependencies organized by `CMakeLists.txt`.

Since the `cmake` command will generate `MakeFile`, a tool or command for Make may may also work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the build folder for your CMake project. For each target, CMake should generate a file called **`C.includecache`**. This file contains the include dependency information.

If, for example, you have a `main.c` file which is including the `stdio.h` and `math.h` headers. The `C.includecache` file will contain an entry like:

```
/path/to/main.c
stdio.h
-
math.h
-
```